# Enable clipboard contents /files to Mac from Windows

Tags: macos, clipboarddata, vnc-viewer

I am trying to setup a Mac mini machine and connected using VNC client.
But I am unable to copy any text contents or file into the Mac mini from my windows machine.

I checked options in VNC viewer and could find only "ServerCutText" and "ClientCutText"

[image]

**I tried enabling options through Screen Sharing.**

[image]

Any idea on what needs to be done for getting clipboard copy and file copy working?

**Screen Sharing window**
[image]

Comment: I am not sure why people do down voting even though they dont answer!

Answer (score -2):

What about enable the screen sharing? [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC76q.png)

Comment: Added the image in original post. It basically says screen sharing is managed by Remote management

Comment: What if you disallow the remote management, then use screen sharing?

Comment: No. Initial setup had Screen sharing enabled.Then based on some posts in apple forums, I changed to Remote management.